# shell command returning an sg device size (Linux)

Tags: linux, shell

I need a shell command that would return an sg device size for me.
I am searching for it over the Internet for almost two hours without any success.

I can do it by writing a program but there has to be a way to get it through a command! I simply cannot find it!

Unfortunatelly, on the dell server I work, sg_inq, and sginfo return Dell's PERC information, and not the device I try to get the information of.

I tried to use the smartctl but it returns a static (and not true) infomation about the device (SSD,) for the number of bytes it returns divided by 512 shows bigger number of sectors that I can access (sic!)

Any [shell command] hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Generic SCSI devices don't have the concept of "size"; they are strictly command devices.

Comment: you have a scsi drive or something? Otherwise I don't understand what you mean bye sg device size!

Comment: I have an SSD device represented by /dev/sg2 name. I would like to ask the system what is the size (or in other words number of sectors) the /dev/sg2 device has.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Yes - that is what I want to do. Query the device asking for its size. Is there a way I can call ioctl() from the shell or I am completely missing something out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am putting an answer here for anyone looking for it.

The ultimate way to either write own program or use smartctl (http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/files/smartmontools/6.0/) and call the following command:

```
#>./smartctl -a /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.0 2012-10-10 r3643 [x86_64-linux-2.6.18-274.18.1.el5] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Vendor:               DELL
Product:              PERC H710P
Revision:             3.13
User Capacity:        179,443,728,384 bytes [179 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Logical Unit id:      --------------------------------
Serial number:        --------------------------------
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Tue Sep 24 17:54:13 2013 EDT
Device does not support SMART

Error Counter logging not supported
Device does not support Self Test logging
```

Comment: Installable on Ubuntu with, `sudo apt-get install smartmontools`

Answer (score 0):

use `#fdisk -l  /dev/sg2`

or `# parted -l /dev/sg2`

Comment: fdisk is for a block device (/dev/sdX, /dev/hd...) I need it for /dev/sgX. Thanks anyway!

Comment: ah sorry. smartmontools seems to have updated support for ssd https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/smartmontools/+bug/1020562 Not sure what error you get with smartctl.

Comment: @RanjithRuban: I don't get any error per se. It is that amount of bytes and the size is incorrect. Number of bytes shown on the screen is off by half of a gig. In other words, if I take the number of bytes, divide by 512, and take it as a number of sectors, I will have an incorrect value.

Comment: @Grzegorz i dont have an ssd disk to check. maybe a bug with the tool. you can check with 6.0 http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/files/smartmontools/6.0/ maybe

Comment: @RanjithRuban: Thanks for the hint. As a matter of fact, because of using Dell Perc controller, I had to download 6.0 smartctl source and build it on my own in order to get SMART data from the SSD. I guess I will try to do something in perl and ioctl()